# I am unable to reach one of my faculty member through email, phone call or even in person, what may I do?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am unable to reach one of my faculty member through email, phone call or even in person, who have agreed on providing me with a recommendation letter. He is not replying to my email, phone number is unavailable and even not coming to the office. I do not know what is wrong or what is the matter, I might miss a deadline of a university which I am really intending to attend.I have given him multiple reminder and not even sure whether he has seen them or not.

Comment: Have you talked to the department secretary/administrative assistant to see if they know where he is?

Comment: Getting a recommendation letter from a family member may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas (from high to low priority / potential efficacy ):

1. Explain administrative stuff of the faculty your situation and ask for help. Maybe they know that he/she is abroad and will come soon. Or he/she is sick and will likely not be able to help you.
2. Find his/her students and explain your situation and ask for help.
3. Talk to some other faculty member asking whether he/she can help you to locate him.